# Why does JavaFX table.getItems().clear() clear the ObservableList as well

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx, tableview, observablelist

I've a JavaFX table defined as:

```
TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>;
//Person Class contains firstName,lastName & email properties
//table has three columns First Name, Last Name & Email
```

An `ObservableList` of `Person`s

```
ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

A background service, which task is to populate the table dynamically by adding entries(`Person` objects) to the `ObservableList persons`.

table is binded as:

```
table.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());
```

Everything is working fine... but I've recently found that if I clear the table items by

```
table.getItems().clear();
```

It does not only clears the table, but also the `ObservableList persons`. I'm wondering if this a bidirectional binding?
Even if I unbind it before calling `getItems().clear()` on the table, it produces same result.
Could someone explain what the point I'm not getting here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set the [`itemsProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#itemsProperty) of a `TableView`, what you are actually doing is to set the reference (pointer) stored in the property, to point to the specified `ObservableList`, rather that making an exact copy of the specified list.

Therefore, when you call [`getItems`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getItems--), it returns the reference to the specified list.

Therefore, if you call `clear()` on this list, you will clear the original `ObservableList`.

---

**Note:**

In most of the cases the binding what you have tried is not necessary:

```
table.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());
```

and it is enough to simply set the `itemsProperty` like

```
table.setItems(service.valueProperty().get());
```

The binding is only necessary if you plan that the reference stored in `valueProperty` will point to **another list** in runtime. In most of the cases it is enough that the table gets notifications on the changes of the list.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Should I make a copy of observable list in order to preserve the original list just in case I need to clear the table and later need the original content? Or is there any better way you would suggest?

Comment: You can call for example `table.setItems(null);` which will set the mentioned pointer to point nowhere -> the table will not display anything and your list is untouched.

Comment: Yep, but for that that I'd have to unbind it table.itemsProperty().unbind(), otherwise it generates exception "A bound value cannot be set" on calling setItems(null).

Comment: Updated the answer about your binding.