# JavaFX - move ListView Item - MVC

Tags: java, listview, javafx-2, mvp

i am new to this java/javafx stuff and i would be very pleased if somebody could help me out of this.

i have the following code :

// Main.java

```
package lernen;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Presenter p = new Presenter();
        View v = new View(p);
        Model m = new Model();

        p.setModel(m);
        p.setView(v);

        Scene scene = new Scene(v.getUI());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Schiebefenster");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

// View.java

```
package lernen;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class View
{
    private Presenter presenter;

    private GridPane pane;

    private Button b1, b2;

    private Label l1, l2;

    // private ObservableList<String> candidates = FXCollections.observableArrayList("a", "b", "c", "d");
    private ObservableList<String> candidates = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private ListView<String> list = new ListView<>(candidates);

    private ObservableList<String> selected = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private ListView<String> list2 = new ListView<>(selected);

    public View(Presenter presenter)
    {
        this.presenter = presenter;
        initView();
    }

    private void initView()
    {
        pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setVisible(true);
        l1 = new Label("Buchstabe");
        pane.add(l1, 0, 0);
        l2 = new Label("Selektiert");
        pane.add(l2, 4, 0);
        b1 = new Button("<");
        pane.add(b1, 2, 2);
        b2 = new Button(">");
        pane.add(b2, 2, 3);
        // list = new ListView<String>();
        pane.add(list, 0, 1, 2, 5);
        // list2 = new ListView<>();
        pane.add(list2, 4, 1, 2, 5);


        b2.setOnAction((ActionEvent) -> {
            String potential = list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (potential != null)
            {
                list.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                candidates.remove(potential);
                selected.add(potential);
            }
        });

        b1.setOnAction((ActionEvent) -> {
            String selectedItem = list2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (selectedItem != null)
            {
                list2.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                selected.remove(selectedItem);
                candidates.add(selectedItem);
            }
        });

    }

    public GridPane getUI()
    {
        return pane;
    }

    public ListView<String> getList()
    {
        return list;
    }

    public ListView<String> getList2()
    {
        return list2;
    }

}
```

// Presenter.java

```
package lernen;

public class Presenter
{
    private View view;

    private Model model;

    public Presenter()
    {
    }

    public void setView(View view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.view.getList().setItems(model.getData());
    }

    public void setModel(Model model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

}
```

// Model.java

```
package lernen;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Model
{
    private ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public Model()
    {
        data.addAll("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
    }

    public ObservableList<String> getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

}
```

The given task is to move a item from the left list to the right and vice versa according to the MVP pattern. The problem is: If i move one letter to the right side, the letter on the left side is still there. I hope u guys can help me with this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the presenter you call

```
this.view.getList().setItems(model.getData());
```

so the list will display the items defined in the `ObservableList` of the model, therefore, when in the event handler of `b2` you call

```
candidates.remove(potential);
```

you actually try to remove the item from a different list (which is actually empty).

I guess the confusion comes from the following:

You defined an `ObservableList`, and you assigned this list to serve as the data model of your `ListView`.

```
private ObservableList<String> candidates = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ListView<String> list = new ListView<>(candidates);
```

and then when in the controller you called

```
this.view.getList().setItems(model.getData());
```

you thought that, this will fill the `candidates` `ObservableList` with the elements of the `ObservableList` stored in the model (all of them elements from the list in the model will be copied to this list). But, when you call `setItems`, you set the reference stored in the [itemsProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#itemsProperty--) to be specified `ObservableList`, therefore it will point to the `ObservableList` stored in the model and no longer to `candidates`.

You can modify this line to:

```
this.view.getList().getItems().addAll(model.getData());
```

The difference is, that in this case `getItems()` will return the `ObservableList` stored in the `itemsProperty` and then all of the elements are copied from the model to this list, but it will still point to `candidates`. In this case the `ObservableList` in the model is not touched.

Or alternatively you can change your listeners as:

```
view.getList2().getItems().remove(selectedItem);
```

which will remove the element from the `ObservableList` in your model also.

The situation is basically the same as here: [Why does JavaFX table.getItems().clear() clear the ObservableList as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223115/why-does-javafx-table-getitems-clear-clear-the-observablelist-as-well/38223231#38223231)

Comment: Many thanks for your help. i solved the problem using a different approach a couple of minutes ago. but youre solution seems to work! *thumbs up*

Answer (score 0):

// presenter.java

```
package lernen;

public class Presenter
{
    private View view;

    private Model model;

    public Presenter()
    {
    }

    public void setView(View view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.view.getList().setItems(model.getData());
    }

    public void setModel(Model model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void RightToLeft() {
        System.out.println("RightToLeft triggered.");
        String selectedItem = view.getList2().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            view.getList2().getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            view.getList2().getItems().remove(selectedItem);
            view.getList().getItems().add(selectedItem);
        }
    }

    public void LeftToRight() {
        System.out.println("LeftToRight triggered.");
        String selectedItem = view.getList().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            view.getList().getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            view.getList().getItems().remove(selectedItem);
            view.getList2().getItems().add(selectedItem);
        }
    }

}
```

// view.java

```
package lernen;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class View
{
    private Presenter presenter;

    private GridPane pane;

    private Button b1, b2;

    private Label l1, l2;

    private ObservableList<String> candidates = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private ListView<String> list = new ListView<>(candidates);

    private ObservableList<String> selected = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private ListView<String> list2 = new ListView<>(selected);

    public View(Presenter presenter)
    {
        this.presenter = presenter;
        initView();
    }

    private void initView()
    {
        pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setVisible(true);
        l1 = new Label("Buchstabe");
        pane.add(l1, 0, 0);
        l2 = new Label("Selektiert");
        pane.add(l2, 4, 0);
        b1 = new Button("<");
        pane.add(b1, 2, 2);
        b2 = new Button(">");
        pane.add(b2, 2, 3);
        list = new ListView<String>();
        pane.add(list, 0, 1, 2, 5);
        list2 = new ListView<>();
        pane.add(list2, 4, 1, 2, 5);

        b1.setOnAction(e -> presenter.RightToLeft());
        b2.setOnAction(e -> presenter.LeftToRight());
    }

    public GridPane getUI()
    {
        return pane;
    }

    public ListView<String> getList()
    {
        return list;
    }

    public ListView<String> getList2()
    {
        return list2;
    }

}
```